# Simple Way for reverse geocode using OpenLayer

Tags: openlayers, reverse-geocoding

I want to make one simple application to get Address for the given latitude and longitude simply reverse geocoding. For this I want to use OpenLayers.

So, how can I do it?

I am also aware about how to use Bing and Google map for reverse geocoding.
Please also suggest any other way for reverse geocoding if it will be difficult through OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers will not allow to do this, you need a database with all the street names and so on...
OpenLayers can be used to show something (marker) at a given location on a map in a browser. If the map images contain street names it may help, but you will not get it as text, the street names will be in the map images as pixels.

Comment: I don't want to locate on map. And also I don't use any map. But here I just want address of given latitude and longitude in string format. Without using bing and google api.

Comment: There is more about this on GIS stackexchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-geocoding